# How to keep a line break for a php variable..?

Tags: php

I tried using `BREAK tag, \n , strip_tags , preg_replace`

BUT i don't understand how to use it..

```
$echo .= ' <div id="chooseForm"> 
            <div class="ads">
               <input type="checkbox" name="blah1" value="blah1" '. isset($_POST['blah1']) ? "checked" : "") .'> <b>blah1 </b>              
               <input type="checkbox" name="blah2" value="blah2" '. (isset($_POST['blah2']) ? "checked" : "") .'> <b>blah2</b>';
```

I should get a 2 lines break for the 2 check boxes (thats what Iam trying for..)

Can anyone pls?

**EDITED:**

I was unable to use properly these  2 functions : `strip_tags , preg_replace`  (I am  not a php coder, so could anyone tell me how to write above code using these functions.. , so i guess then it gonna work..

Comment: Are you sure some external CSS isn't affecting it?

Comment: as far as I know CSS shouldnt efect me... what I strongly feel is, I was unable to use  these 2 things: strip_tags , preg_replace  properly.. could you please tell how to write above code using these tags..?

Comment: The `<br>` tags should create line breaks. You don't need any of those functions.

Comment: I do not see you trying to use the functions mentioned above nor why you would need them.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you're trying to do and what about it isn't working. Your code puts one line break after the first checkbox, and two line breaks after the second one.

Comment: i didnt showned using those functions in above code, since I didnt udnestood how to use those functions proeprly for above code, thats why I came here.. but i found in other websites saying that we can get line breaks using  strip_tags or preg_replace , pls show me a exact syntax for above code that works for me.. i also tried <br> tag, even that didnt worked..

Comment: are you trying to remove them `<br/>` ? just to clarify...

Comment: now i removed those <br/> tags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning to a variable called $echo. Also echo this once you are done:

```
echo $echo;
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gxz-94w

Perhaps you wish to render newline characters, in which case you should wrap your output in `<pre>` tags.

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/e66-jq8

Comment: sory bro, actually i shud use line breaks inside $echo variable.. i cannot use external echo.. so, any other idea..?

Comment: @John But there are already line breaks inside the $echo variable. See those `<br/>` tags? Those are line breaks. I am not sure what you mean by `external echo`, but if you don't write your string to the output, you will never see it.

Comment: wow! it works like a  charm.. just <pre> tag helped me to ahcive this .. lol.. i thought to use some stupid fucntions for line breaks.. echo $echo; somewhere calling in some file (even I donno where its calling, its  a big code), anyway , thanx a lot bro.. gud day! :)